# Is it possible to make NERDtree use :lcd instead of :cd?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, nerdtree

In vim if you use the :lcd command, it will change the working directory for the current window only.  I like this because many plugins respect it.  I can have one project open in one tab, and in another tab have another project and use Command-T in both.

NERDTree's :cd command will change the working directory for all windows / tabs.  So if I had previously set the lcd for different windows, NERDTree in essence stomps on that.

I love NERDTree but is there any way I can teach it to use the lcd command instead of the cd command?

Comment: By the way, that's a very valid question. I wonder why a plugin that exists for so long doesn't have that functionality. It seems to me that lots of people would like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git grep lcd` reveals that it is not used anywhere. Thus I think your only choices are:

*1)* Patch it in yourself (`git grep cd` says there are 3 places where `:cd` is used).

*2)* Open an issue report on github (but make sure to go through the list of open issues before that, there are 132 of them. :-) )